# which design pattern is used for TestRunner class in junit

Tags: java, design-patterns, junit

I was trying to understand the design pattern used for TestRunner (package junit.textui) class of JUnit. The TestRunner class is extending a listener
and has a reference of listener.

If it is the Observer design pattern, then why is it
extending listener? it should have only reference of listener.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This site is to help people solve their specific programming problems. Please have a look at help centre http://stackoverflow.com/help to see what questions and how you should ask here.

Comment: @Ean This seems like a "practical, answerable problem" that is "unique to software development". There's a little subtlety to it, too—TestRunner implements TestListener but doesn't seem to use it.

Answer (score 3):

[`junit.textui.TestRunner`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/javadoc/junit/textui/TestRunner.html) conforms to the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), but it's the *observer*, not the *subject*. At least, it *would* be the observer—it isn't anymore.

JUnit exposes the [TestListener](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/junit/framework/TestListener.java) interface: The [TestResult](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/junit/framework/TestResult.java) class runs a TestCase, calling its own methods `startTest` and `endTest`. TestResult also contains a list of TestListener instances, and notifies all of them whenever a test is started or ended. This is the quintessential Observer pattern: TestResult is the subject, notifying its collection of TestListener instances, one of which could be TestRunner adding itself to the list.

That said, [TestRunner doesn't currently add itself as a listener to TestResult](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/junit/textui/TestRunner.java), and has empty implementations of its required `testStarted`, `testEnded`, and `testFailed` methods. Instead, it adds a [ResultPrinter](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/junit/textui/ResultPrinter.java) to the list of Listeners; I assume this was factored out of TestRunner at some point.

So, TestRunner is set up to be an Observer, but it no longer acts like one. All told, this actually demonstrates a strength of design patterns: It allows the opportunity to refactor the code and separate behavior by coding against those specific interfaces.